# Why does this script crash Blender 3.6.5?

Tags: scripting

I think this it's this line `obj.hide_viewport = False`

```py
def deleteAll():
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    for collection in bpy.data.collections:
        for obj in collection.all_objects:
            obj.hide_viewport = False
            obj.hide_set(False)
            obj.select_set(True)
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')                
    bpy.ops.object.delete()

deleteAll()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short use

```
for obj in collection.objects:
```

or

```
objs = [o for o in collection.all_objects]
for obj in objs:
```

or

```
for obj in collection.all_objects[:]:
```

to call objects in collection.

Known problem with changing Object.hide_viewport, Object.hide_select or Object.hide_render while iteration over Collection.all_objects. That breaks because the cache is rebuild and there´s an invalid memory access. Not only 3.6.5, same in 2.9.3 for example.

See here: [manual](https://docs.blender.org/api/master/info_gotcha.html#unfortunate-corner-cases)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to delete all objects in the file ?

Try

`bpy.data.batch_remove(bpy.data.objects)`

[Link to the docs](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.BlendData.html#bpy.types.BlendData.batch_remove)